# printing multiple images url's with different id's

Tags: python, image, loops, selenium, src

I'm trying to print multiple images url's with different id's.
I'm using selenium in python and I have been trying this code:

```
    for i in range (5000):
            path= "product-collection-image-"+str(i)
            try:
                    image = driver.find_element_by_id(path)
                    img_src = image.get_attribute("src")
                    print img_src
            except:
                    pass
```

All the images that I want to print have an id called "product-collection image-" and then some integers that go from 1 to 5000.

With this code I can print the image urls but they come in a numerical order. I want it in the order that they come in the page, because I want to match it with other fields.

I am a newbie at Python, so I have some difficulties with complex syntax.
I've been trying to use regex in

path= "product-collection-image-"+.*

but it gives me a syntax error

Is there a way to, with selenium, grab all elements with a range of ids and print it in the order that they come on the page?
Also, in a list, how can I get attributes, like the src attribute?

Sorry, but I'm starting the learning curve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the *partial `id` match*:

```
image_srcs = [img.get_attribute("src") 
              for img in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id^="product-collection-image-"]')]
```

where `^=` means "starts with".

Note that, this way you would get the image elements in the order they appear on the page.

Comment: @NelsonGomes sure, if you want to print them one by one. I've used list comprehension to collect src values into a list.

Comment: I've made this way: for img in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id^="product-collection-image-"]'):
         imgurl= img.get_attribute("src")
         print imgurl

Comment: I really want to print line for line. I need to grab this data and put it into Excel row. i need also to start learning Excel modules in Python in order to create file, dump data into column A, dump other into column B, etc, etc. Right now, I'm doing this mannualy. Many thanks alecxe!!! I must compensate you!